# Regular Expression creation for phone number

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a single regular expression to validate phone numbers. Below numbers should be

1111111111 or 111-111-1111 or 111.111.1111 - should fail and at the same time 767-789-9876 or 7677899876 should pass

I have come up with ^(?!([0-9])\1{2}[^d]*\1{3}[^d]*\1{4}$), but it only helps validate repetitive digits, alphanumeric characters and all succeed. Can anyone help me improve my regex?

Comment: This has been answered before, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Comment: I already checked that it does not help validate repetitive scenario

Answer (score 0):

based on your examples, use this pattern

```
^(?!(\d)([.-]?\1)+$)(\d{3}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/239)